# Цвета фона в консоли PHPStorm

Tags: phpstorm

Если вывод в консоли PHPStorm имеет цвет фона, то выводит в таком виде:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

чтобы увидеть текст, приходится выделять его.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно настроить цвета в консоли PHPStorm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пробовали настраивать:

> Settings --> Editor --> Colors&Fonts -->  - Console Colors  - Console Fonts

[введите сюда описание ссылки](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/configuring-color-scheme-for-consoles.html)